# Getting length of input in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, forms

Trying to show a message of how many chars were used for a text field as-you-type (similar to the comments in Stackoverflow)

I'm using AngularJs with a `form`.
Code looks like this:

```
  <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="inp" ng-model="myval" ng-minlength="10">
    <span>
      You have used --INPUT-LENGTH--
    </span>
  </form>
```

How can I make `--INPUT-LENGTH--` show the current length of the input field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple use the `.length` attribute

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="inp" ng-model="myval">
    <span>
        You have used {{myval.length}}
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add a crucial restriction. Sorry for adding this late.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form you can rely on angular binding mechanism which will update dependent variables when things change.

```
<form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="inp" ng-model="myval">
    <span>
      You have used {{myval.length}} characters
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add a crucial restriction. Sorry for adding this late.